# Java - Send file to a user folder

Tags: java, file

I'm using JAXB to create XML files. I want files to be downloaded on the user pc.
Here is my code, actually it's creating the file to the server :

```
OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream("E:\\"+n+".xml");
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(F6005.class);
javax.xml.bind.Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(javax.xml.bind.Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, new Boolean(true));
jaxbMarshaller.marshal(f6005, file);
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/F6207done.jsp").forward(request,  response);
```

Instead i want to send the file to the a user folder after he clicks on Download button. How can i do it ?

Comment: Please specify, do you want to save generated xml fo a user folder on the server side, or force browser to save downloaded file to a user home folder on client machine? If latter I'm afraid it's difficult to achieve as user is free to select the folder where donwloaded file will be stored.

Comment: Your code is incomplete. It's probably missing `nse);` at the end. PS: You can use just `true` instead of `new Boolean(true)`.

Comment: @lospejos  Yes, i want to force browser to save the file to a user home folder on client machine, Downloads folder as default

Comment: if you want to directly save your file to the client computer's user home through backend servlet application then the answer is no, it can't be done.

Comment: "it can't be done" At least, using normal / standard approaches. To accompish this, you have to have some additional software installed on user's PC, and this software could get and execute commands from you (including file saving in certain folders).

Answer (score 1):

Demand OutputStream from the response. Change the content type and send the data. The browser will render the file in the described format.

```
OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
response.setContentType("text/xml; charset=UTF-8");
jaxbMarshaller.marshal(f6005, os);
```

Comment: i tried this, the browser displays the file, but it's not downloading it automatically..

Comment: Do you mean you want a file to be downloaded to the user system without his permission? Would you want a Web application to do that to your system?

Comment: yes. The user is supposed the create the file by introducing informations  he need through a web form,  and receive an XML file as result.

Comment: In any case, you cannot dictate the Server to forcefully introduce a file to a user system. You can, however, try doing this from client side.
Following link might help: https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, in case someone needs it :

```
       response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+nn+".xml");
        response.setContentType("text/xml; charset=UTF-8");
        OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
        javax.xml.bind.Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(javax.xml.bind.Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, new Boolean(true));
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(f6005, outStream);
```